# маппинг сервлетов аннотациями

Tags: spring, servlet, аннотации

Понимаю, что нет маппинга для сервлета "dispatcher", но как и куда его добавить в проект, не используя web.xml, (все объявлено аннотациями)? Или я что то не так понял?

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

WebAppConfig:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver(){
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
}
```

и соответственно ексепшн:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/bootstrap.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' 
окт 02, 2016 9:35:39 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound 
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/style.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' 
окт 02, 2016 9:35:39 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound 
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/font-awesome.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: Где у вас хранятся ресурсы bootstrap.css в проекте? Напишите полный путь.

Comment: @MrFylypenko src/main/resources/webapp/css

Comment: `registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**")` указывает на то, что запросы должны быть такие: `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}pages/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`, а `addResourceLocations("/pages/")`, указывает на местоположение ресурсов, в данном случае `src/main/resources/webapp/pages/css`

Comment: @MrFylypenko Спасибо огромное! Оформите пожалуйста как ответ я отмечу как верный!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде не правильная адресация для получения ресурсов.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**")
```

указывает на то, что подключаемые ресурсы должны быть такие:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}pages/css/bootstrap.‌​css"
       rel="stylesheet">
```

а параметр

```
addResourceLocations("/pages/")
```

указывает на местоположение ресурсов в каталоге webapp:

```
src/main/resources/webapp/pages/css
```